# vs2015- setup.exe windows application is not working in other machines with same machine configuration

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015, windows, windowsformshost

I have created windows application in vs2015  and run the application and build the application. i need to create that application to installable exe files could be run on other machines.

When Publish the Files, It created a Setup.exe publish files, I have clicked and installed in my machine working perfectly.

when I have given the setup to other machines with same configuration, it is not working, it has installed in other machines, when I click the application, nothing shows, and no response.

[image]

Comment: Is the `setup.exe` written in C#? Or it is written in C/C++ *(or generated by Visual Studio)*? What is the error? In the second case *(C/C++/generated)* it can be, that there are missing dependencies (Visual Studio Runtime Libraries) in the target machine. But when there is no error displayed, perhaps something other is missing (a data file?).

Comment: @Julo C# windows application and i have right click the project and publish the project, it created a exe, its working in my machine and others have a problem ,Same Environment setup configured in other machines.

Comment: I do not use the 'publish' feature. I tried it once *(a few years ago)*, but the result was not that was I was expecting *(or what I needed)*. I'm not so sure of the exact 'result'. As far as I remember, there was a error, but I do not remember whether the publishing process failed, or the output file was not usable. Since this failure I do not use the 'publish' feature and always use another way to build release output *(standard release build + scripts to compress, sign, make installers e.t.c.)*.

Comment: In previous version I have used and execuatable files by using this method https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/19x10e5c(v=vs.100).aspx ,so  What is the use of publish method  over this.

Comment: I remembered something similar was in my GUI application. Since Visual Studio 2015 exceptions that were not caught by my code were ignored *(program did not raise an exception visible for user, but the code was not executed)*. I had a hard time to figure out why data/controls were in incorrect state *(the code was not executed)*. It was caused by an exception. Try to add try/catch to your root code and also add 'global exception catcher' to display or log exception.